# Page not returning data using React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I am creating a pizza website but after trying to get the data from the database it is showing an error something like this

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lk8X.png)

[error2 in redux devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV1Mr.png)

this is the Action and Routes code:
[Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh5mw.png)
[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YlE2.png)

I am following a Youtube Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4mYkWuFs80&list=PLN4MUG0f6hp1lTDxczIbp5WGzvoA5UCse&index=2

he told to restart the server in the video but even restarting its not working.

Comment: The error is for 404 it means api not found. Please check on which port your server is running. for example if your server is running on port :8000 then in action function you can put the url like : const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/getallpizzas")

Comment: My server is running on Port 5000 and website is opening on localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added the proxy variable in your package.json. The person is adding it on timestamp [6:45](https://youtu.be/p4mYkWuFs80?list=PLN4MUG0f6hp1lTDxczIbp5WGzvoA5UCse&t=408). Example:

#### package.json

```
"proxy" : "http://localhost:8000/"
```

And that is why your axios.get has only "/api/getallpizzas"

Other option is to add the full path in your axios.get like so:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/getallpizzas')
.then((response)=>{
console.log(response);
dispatch({type:'GET_PIZZAS_SUCCES', payload: response.data})
})
.catch((error)=>{
dispatch({type:'GET_PIZZAS_FAILED', payload:error})
})
```

Another possible error might be that your server is not running.

Comment: I have done all that, still do not know what is the issue??

Comment: My server is running on Port 5000 and website is opening on localhost:3000

Comment: 1. That means you have to configure your axios calls too. Or that being said run your proxy on "proxy":"https://localhost:5000/.
2. Another good thing to do is test your server via postman. Try to run the server go to postman and send a GET request for all the pizzas and see if it would go through